# I am not able to select a content item in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I have installed a package in my sitecore instance and all the contents are there in my content tree. However I am not able to select the content item, on clicking the content item its throwing an error--"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have tried re-installing the package but the issue is still there.

Comment: There may be many reasons of such a behavior. Maybe some template it missing? Try using `/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx` tool instead of Content Editor and see if you can access that item there.

Comment: I am able to select the item in /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx. Any idea why I am not able to select in Content editor. I wanted to check the template from which that item is created.

Comment: You can see the template of any item in `dbbrowser` at the top of the middle grey section, e.g. if you select `/sitecore/content/home` item you should see at the top `/sitecore/content/home : Sample Item` where `Sample Item` is template name

Comment: tried that but template name is missing for that item.

Comment: It means that your package doesn't contain that template. You can unzip the package and in `items` folder find xml under that item directory and check template id in it.

Answer (score 0):

there is multiple resone behind this issue on your sitecore screen, but the most frequent reason behind this, templete missing againts the installed Items.

So first look into the Template section, related templates are installed correctly, then install the Items package in sitecore.